# turning list of matrixes into a vector

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

I have found many solutions the other way round but none this way. I have a list of matrixes and need to have them as a vector. I could take each element, name it, and than put it in a vector. But I'm sure there is a better way!

```
zerooklein <- lapply(1:10, function(x){genweb(10, 5, dens=2)})
zeroomittel <- lapply(1:10, function(x){genweb(10, 20, dens=2)})
zeroogroß <- lapply(1:10, function(x){genweb(10, 80, dens=2)})
```

these are my lists.

```
size <- c(this should contain all the singel matrices )
sizef <- sapply(size, function(x) nested(get(x), method="ALL"))
plot(capscale(formula = scale(sizef) ~ 1))
```

and this is what i want to do with them.

Comment: You question doesn't appear to make sense.  The `nested` function takes a `web` as it's argument, not a vector.  You should provide more context so others can understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Even better, provide examples of what the intermediate objects should look like.

Comment: I want to apply several metrics(ALL) on several matrices(zeroo). so `size`should be a vector of the (names? of the )singel matrices. so that nested can take each matrix and apply all methods on them. It then should return a vector with the calculated metrics for each matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the names of the your LISTS, note the 'zeroo...' objects are not vectors, you create that vector explicitly.  The only vector in this entire process is the following one line:

```
size <- c("zerooklein", "zeroomittel", "zeroogroß")
```

Now the rest of this is all lists and matrices.  Each of your 'zeroo...' objects is a list of matrices and therefore must be looped over to pass to `nested`.  As such, you need to loop over not only each 'zeroo...' object but also each matrix within the 'zeroo...', hence a double loop.  The following call does the job.

```
sizef <- lapply(size, function(x) sapply(get(x), function(y) nested(y, method="ALL")))
```

You cannot just use two `sapply` statements otherwise it will automatically 'rbind' your results together, which it appears is not your goal.  Therefore, you have a list of three matrices at this point.  You can merge these together with `do.call`.

```
size_merged <- do.call("cbind", sizef)
```

Now you can plot your final matrix

```
plot(capscale(scale(size_merged) ~ 1))
```